How to expand vector field to higher-order terms in parallel transport?
I was wondering how to expand vector field to higher order terms in parallel transport.
Suppose that I have field in either covariant or contravariant basis:
$u^i$ or $v_i$
Parallel transport requires that:
$$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial\xi^j}=-{\Gamma^i}_{jk}u^k$$
$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial\xi^j}={\Gamma^k}_{ij}v_k$$
Now I would be interested in expanding it to at least 2nd order term (if possible I would like to know method to expand to any order term):
$$u^i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,\ldots)=u^i+\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial\xi^j}\Delta x^j+\frac12\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}\Delta x^j\Delta x^k+\ldots$$
$$v_i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,\ldots)=v_i+\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial\xi^j}\Delta x^j+\frac12\frac{\partial^2v_i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}\Delta x^j\Delta x^k+\ldots$$
I can replace 1st order terms:
$$u^i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,\ldots)=u^i-{\Gamma^i}_{jk}u^k\Delta x^j+\frac12\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}\Delta x^j\Delta x^k+\ldots$$
$$v_i(\xi^1+\Delta x^1,\xi^2+\Delta x^2,\ldots)=v_i+{\Gamma^k}_{ij}v_k\Delta x^j+\frac12\frac{\partial^2v_i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}\Delta x^j\Delta x^k+\ldots$$
Now, what can be done with 2nd order and higher terms? Can they be replaced with something containing Christoffel symbols?
Edit:
Not really certain about this solution, but I tried to go further starting with first order term and applying derivative to both sides...
$$\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial\xi^j}=-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}u^l\Bigg/\frac\partial{\partial\xi^k}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}=-\frac{{\Gamma^i}_{jl}}{\partial\xi^k}u^l-{\Gamma^i}_{jl}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial\xi^k}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}=-\frac{{\Gamma^i}_{jl}}{\partial\xi^k}u^l+{\Gamma^i}_{jl}{\Gamma^l}_{km}u^m$$
$$\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}=-\frac{{\Gamma^i}_{jl}}{\partial\xi^k}u^l+{\Gamma^i}_{jm}{\Gamma^m}_{kl}u^l$$
$$\frac{\partial^2u^i}{\partial\xi^j\partial\xi^k}=(-\frac{{\Gamma^i}_{jl}}{\partial\xi^k}+{\Gamma^i}_{jm}{\Gamma^m}_{kl})u^l$$
